# Como obtener el valor cada vez que selecciono el elemento de un array en mi formulario?

Tags: angular

Me podrian ayudar por favor con el siguiente problema que estoy presentando hace varios dias y no he logrado resolver.
Cabe decir que soy novato en este tema.

Tengo un formulario el cual tiene unas listas desplegables depndientes. Los valores vienen desde una base de datos (job, reference, module). Cada registro de mi BD contienen estos 3 campos.
Deseo que al seleccionar JOB, me despliege los valores sin repetirlos (esto ya lo he logrado). Y a su vez, deseo que se me carguen en la otra lista, los valores REFERENCE correspondienta a cada JOB seleccionado. De la misma forma para MODULE (dependera de REFERENCE)

El problema que tengo es que cuando selecciono por ejemplo el JOB 10075, me trae el erray correspondiente (1 solo- OK), pero cuando selecciono otro 10074,me trae 2 arrays (pero uno de ellos es el 10075). Y si me devuelvo a seleccionar el 10075, me carga los ultimos 2 onsultados. Lo otro que sucede es que cuando actualizo mi navegador y selecciono uno de ellos si me los trae.

Como puedo resolver este problema, Hay una forma de formatear los valores cada vez que se invoca el evento SelectionChange?

A continuacion les comparto parte del codigo que estoy desarrollando:

export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {

```
  selectedProject: any=[];    
  

   listProject: Project[]=[];
   listProjectNotRepeat: Project[]=[];
   listProjectGet: Project[]=[];

   listReference: Project[]=[];
   listReferenceNotRepeat: Project[]=[];
   listReferenceGet: Project[]=[];
   
   listModule: Project[]=[];
   listModuleNotRepeat: Project[]=[];
   listModuleGet: Project[]=[];
   
    listJob: StructureBom[] = [];       // lista de productos
```

listJobFilter: StructureBom[] = [];       // lista de productos filtrados
jobSelected!: StructureBom;

listStructureReport: Report[] = [];

typePartClass: string = "SM";

```
 formFilter: FormGroup;
```

columnsTable: string[] = ['description4','plant','ecogroupId','partNum','revisionNum','mtlSeq','mtlPartNum', 'qtyPer', 'uomCode', 'relatedOperation', 'pullAsAsm', 'viewAsAsm', 'mfgComment'];
dataStructureReport = new MatTableDataSource(this.listStructureReport);
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) tablePagination! : MatPaginator;

constructor(
private fb                   : FormBuilder,
private _structureBomService : StructureBomService,
private _utilityService      : UtilityService,
private _projectService: ProjectService,

```
){
this.formFilter = this.fb.group({
    project:['', Validators.required],
  reference:['', Validators.required],
    module:['', Validators.required]
})


// Select Project
this._projectService.list().subscribe({
  
  next: (response) => {
  if(response.status) this.listProject = response.value
  {
    const list = response.value as Project[];
    this.listProject = list.filter(p => p.isActive == 1);
    console.log(this.listProject);
  }

  let projectNotRepeat = this.listProjectNotRepeat; 
  
  // project no repeat
  this.listProject.map((nameProject, i) => { i == 0 ? nameProject : projectNotRepeat.filter(sinRep => {
         return sinRep.project === nameProject.project 
      }).length == 0 ? projectNotRepeat.push(nameProject) : nameProject
  });
  
  this.listProjectGet = projectNotRepeat;
 // console.log(this.listProjectGet);

},
  error:(e)=>{}

})
```

}

ngOnInit(): void {

}

onSelect(value: any): void{

```
console.log('project-->', value);      

 let valorBuscado = value;

 const resultado = this.listProject.filter(s => s.project === valorBuscado)
  
 //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // reference no repeat
 let referenceNotRepeat = this.listReferenceNotRepeat;
 resultado.map((referenceProject, i) => { i == 0 ? referenceProject : referenceNotRepeat.filter(sinRep => { 
          return sinRep.reference === referenceProject.reference
    }).length == 0 ? referenceNotRepeat.push(referenceProject) : referenceProject
});


this.listReferenceGet = referenceNotRepeat;
console.log(this.listReferenceGet);
```

}

**HTML**

Reports

```
    <mat-card-content>
        <form [formGroup]="formFilter" (ngSubmit)="searchStructureBom()">
            <mat-grid-list cols="5" rowHeight="70px">




                <mat-grid-tile>
                    <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
                        <mat-label>Select Job</mat-label>
                            <mat-select formControlName ="project" [(ngModel)]="selectedProject.project" (selectionChange)="onSelect($event.value)">
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of listProjectGet" [value]="option.project">{{option.project}}</mat-option>                            
                            </mat-select>              
                    </mat-form-field>
                </mat-grid-tile>

                <mat-grid-tile>
                    <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
                        <mat-label>Select Reference</mat-label>
                            <mat-select formControlName ="reference" [(ngModel)]="selectedProject.reference" >
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of listReferenceGet" [value]="option.reference">{{option.reference}}</mat-option>                            
                            </mat-select>              
                    </mat-form-field>
                </mat-grid-tile>

                <mat-grid-tile>
                    <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
                        <mat-label>Select Module</mat-label>
                            <mat-select formControlName ="module">
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of listModuleGet" [value]="option.module">{{option.module}}</mat-option>                            
                            </mat-select>              
                    </mat-form-field>
                </mat-grid-tile>
       
                <mat-grid-tile >
                    <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
                        <mat-label>Type Part Class </mat-label>
                            <mat-select [(value)] = "typePartClass">
                                <mat-option value ="SM">Nesting</mat-option>
                                <mat-option value ="ST">Inventor</mat-option>
                            </mat-select>                
                    </mat-form-field>
                </mat-grid-tile>
                
                <mat-grid-tile>
                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="formFilter.invalid" type="submit" class="button-search">
                        <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>Search
                    </button>
                </mat-grid-tile>


            </mat-grid-list>
        </form>

        <button mat-raised-button color="accent" [disabled]="listStructureReport.length < 1" (click) = "exportExcel()">
            <mat-icon>feed</mat-icon>Export File
        </button>

        <div class="mat-elevation-z2" style="margin-top: 15px;">
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataStructureReport">

                <ng-container matColumnDef="description4">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Company</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.description4}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="plant">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Plant</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.plant}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="ecogroupId">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>EcoGroupID</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.ecogroupId}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="partNum">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>PartNum</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.partNum}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                
                <ng-container matColumnDef="revisionNum">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>RevisionNum</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.revisionNum}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="mtlSeq">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>MtlSeq</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.mtlSeq}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="mtlPartNum">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>MtlPartNum</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.mtlPartNum}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="qtyPer">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>QtyYPer</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.qtyPer}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="uomCode">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>UomCode</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.uomCode}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="relatedOperation">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>RelatedOperation</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.relatedOperation}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="pullAsAsm">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>PullAsAsm</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.pullAsAsm}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="viewAsAsm">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ViewAsAsm</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.viewAsAsm}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="mfgComment">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>MfgComment</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.mfgComment}} </td>
                </ng-container>


                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsTable"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsTable;"></tr>

            </table>
            <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,20]" showFirstLastButton></mat-paginator>
        </div>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

JSON

```
[
{
    "idProject": 1,
    "nameProject": "test",
    "idCategory": 1,
    "descriptionCategory": "Bom_Hierarchy_SM",
    "descriptionProject1": 20,
    "descriptionProject2": "2500.00",
    "isActive": 1,
    "project": "10074",
    "reference": "02",
    "module": "01"
},
{
    "idProject": 2,
    "nameProject": "test01",
    "idCategory": 1,
    "descriptionCategory": "Bom_Hierarchy_SM",
    "descriptionProject1": 100,
    "descriptionProject2": "120.00",
    "isActive": 1,
    "project": "10074",
    "reference": "01",
    "module": "01"
},
{
    "idProject": 3,
    "nameProject": "test02",
    "idCategory": 1,
    "descriptionCategory": "Bom_Hierarchy_SM",
    "descriptionProject1": 222,
    "descriptionProject2": "100.00",
    "isActive": 1,
    "project": "10075",
    "reference": "01",
    "module": "01"
},
{
    "idProject": 4,
    "nameProject": "test03",
    "idCategory": 1,
    "descriptionCategory": "Bom_Hierarchy_SM",
    "descriptionProject1": 20,
    "descriptionProject2": "10.00",
    "isActive": 1,
    "project": "10075",
    "reference": "01",
    "module": "02"
},
{
    "idProject": 5,
    "nameProject": "test04",
    "idCategory": 1,
    "descriptionCategory": "Bom_Hierarchy_SM",
    "descriptionProject1": 200,
    "descriptionProject2": "60.00",
    "isActive": 1,
    "project": "10075",
    "reference": "01",
    "module": "03"
},
{
    "idProject": 9,
    "nameProject": "test05",
    "idCategory": 1,
    "descriptionCategory": "Bom_Hierarchy_SM",
    "descriptionProject1": 20,
    "descriptionProject2": "111.00",
    "isActive": 1,
    "project": "10074",
    "reference": "02",
    "module": "01"
}
```

]

[image: asi es como se ve mi formulario. Este es dependiente, es decir, luego que seleccione el JOB, se deben cargar los valores de REFERENCE.]

**Este es el JSON que obtengo cada vez que cambio la seleccion**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probaste limpiando el array antes de ejecutarlo otra vez?

Comment: Si claro, De acuerdo a lo que he leido, al parecer estoy usando el mismo formGroup para las 3 listas autocomplete. Entonces recomiendan hacer una iteracion para cada una, pero no he podido lograrlo aun.